# Why does it feel colder before frost forms?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there a scientific explanation as to why the air temperature feels colder before frost is formed/seen?

I'm thinking this has something to do with heat transfer between the air and something else, as I think frost is formed by a condensation reaction from water vapour to liquid. However, I don't think I have the full picture here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It falls under the title [of condensation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condensation) It is also colder before rain drops , but the difference is not so obvious in body senses.

you already have said it:

> frost is formed by a condensation reaction from water vapour to liquid. However, I thought condensation reactions were supposed to release heat, so I don't think I have the full picture here.

For frost to fall, heat is released and the heat released on contact with the surface , raises the temperature of the surface which heats the air too, so the air after frost is hotter in the region where  frost condenses.

I tried unsuccessfully to find links for this. The words are preempted by the climate and weather articles. [Here is a link](https://opentextbc.ca/physicstestbook2/chapter/phase-change-and-latent-heat/) that calculates the heat released during phase transitions, with examples, and phase transitions release a lot of heat. Frost is a phase transition, and the heat , radiation , will partially go to the air too, not only the surface it condenses on.